# Will */5 hours in a Cron job be done at 1pm the next day?

Tags: cron

We need a Cron job that runs every 5 hours and that takes a little longer than 4 hours to complete,

If it's scheduled in a Cron job as */5 for the hours part will it run at 1pm the second day?

Ie. Will the first day be 0,5,10,15,20 and then 1,6,11,21, (and so forth...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not.

Assuming the minute part is fixed (which makes the full cron expression into `0 */5 * * *`), the cron job will always be triggered at 0th, 5th, 10th, 15th, and 20th hours every day.

In addition to that, the next cron job will be triggered regardless of whether the previous cron job has already been completed or not. For example, if the cron job at 5th hour takes 7 hours to complete, the cron job at 10th hour will still be triggered on time.